# ModuleNotFoundError when running Jupyternotebook in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, bert-language-model

I have created a virtual environment using Anaconda and installed all the packages I need based on a requirements text file. Followed by installing the ipykernel. This is the code I've used.

```
conda create --name venv_nlp python=3.8
conda activate venv_nlp
pip install -r requirements.txt
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=venv_nlp
```

Afterwards, I did entered pip list in the anaconda prompt to see the list of packages installed.
The package I needed, bertopic, is in the list.

I've opened my Jupyternotebook, changed kernel to venv_nlp.
However, when running

```
from bertopic import BERTopic
```

I do get an error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py:287: DeprecationWarning: `should_run_async` will not call `transform_cell` automatically in the future. Please pass the result to `transformed_cell` argument and any exception that happen during thetransform in `preprocessing_exc_tuple` in IPython 7.17 and above.
  and should_run_async(code)
```

And when I do

```
!pip list
```

I do get a warning and the list of packages installed. Bertopic is not in it:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py:287: DeprecationWarning: `should_run_async` will not call `transform_cell` automatically in the future. Please pass the result to `transformed_cell` argument and any exception that happen during thetransform in `preprocessing_exc_tuple` in IPython 7.17 and above.
  and should_run_async(code)
```

My virtual environment path is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\virtualenv_nlp
And it seems that the code is looking for the packages in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ instead. Thus creating a ModuleNotFoundError.

May I know what should be done here? I am quite new with creating virtual environments.

Answer (score 1):

This error could be due to several reasons:

1. The package *bertopic* should not be installed properly therefore you can re-
   install this package while your venv_nlp environment is activated:

Command for re-install

```
 pip install bertopic
```

2. There could be some missing dependencies in your environments. You can use the following command  while your venv_nlp environment is activated:

pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: I've done the reinstallations but I am still getting the same error

Comment: re-install seemed to fix it for me.